# Need to build C++(ms build) project in jenkins which has dependancy in multiple repositories which is stored bit bucket with git repository

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, bitbucket

Need to build C++(ms build) project in Jenkins which has a dependency in multiple repositories which is stored in by bitbucket in a git repository.

Need MSBuild script format too.

Comment: Hi Seeker, there isn't a clear question here, please clarify what you're asking. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: #1 Are your bitbucket repositories public? #2 Is a proof of concept or a enterprise requirement? #3  Depend on it I can advice you an scalable solution or just a quickly solution!

Comment: I need to build a project which has dependancy in multiple repositories in bit bucket. Need to write msbuld script for it. Need a sample script

Comment: Bit bucket repositories are not public